# Wildcard character in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is this:

When I use a keyword with `like` as `%abc, xyz%` it is showing results, but when I use `xyz,abc` with `like` as `%xyz,abc%` it's not showing any results because the pattern is not matched.

Is there any way for this problem?

Comment: What are you expecting it to find?

Comment: Are you saying you have a comma separated list of items... stored in one field?

Comment: Show your query with your database structures and some values

Comment: Yes I have comma separated list of item

Answer (score 3):

Use 2 seperate `like` conditions

```
select * from your_table
where your_column like '%abc%'
and your_column like '%xyz%'
```

Answer (score 2):

use OR

```
where your_column like '%abc%'
OR your_column like '%xyz%'
```

Comment: Thanks but my query is being dynamic So it would be complicated ,can u suggest any other way .